# Not able to install Scala 2.13 using apt-get

Tags: apt, scala

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

I run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install scala
```

This installs scala 2.11.12

but this is an outdated version. The real version of the programming language is 2.13.0

I googled and googled but everything points to very old and outdated articles.

Comment: Ubuntu repositories are always far behind latest versions. Did you try to download the [last official deb package](https://scala-lang.org/download/), then [`sudo dpkg -i scala-2.13.0.deb && sudo apt install -f`](https://askubuntu.com/a/40781/349837). [See also](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-sbt-on-ubuntu-for-scala-and-java-projects/)?

Comment: I didn't want to download manually. this way I'll always have to download by myself. I resolved the problem by installing SDKMAN.

Comment: Nice, you should answer your own question with that. TIL.

Answer (score 0):

As the OP noted, running apt-get installs an old version of Scala, and a solution it to use SDKMan instead.

Install SdkMan (https://sdkman.io/)

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Use sdkman to install scala

```
sdk install scala 2.13.8
```